# Cron not running in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cron, ubuntu-16.04

Following is my `cron` on Ubuntu 16.04. I tried running the script manually and did not get any error but it won't run automatically. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.

```
*/1 * * * * http://app.example.com/dosomething/example_method
```

P.S. I want the script to run on its own every 1 minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the command to execute.  Perhaps you want something like the following.

```
 curl http://app.example.com/dosomething/example_method
```

Also, *cron* jobs that generate output or an error message and send it by mail, so check the email of the account under which the job is scheduled to run, so see what the problem is.

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: But you accepted the answer? Is curl installed? What do you read in cron's email messages?

Comment: Yes curl was installed and its working fine now.